# How should I specify a tab in a website to read with webread()?

Tags: matlab, web, web-scraping

Considering this web page: http://tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=778253364357513 , that I like to read the contents of the one of the tabs on above of the page (most left violet tab that is written "حقیقی- حقوقی" on it for example. How should I specify that in my webread() function to go on that tab and read it's information?
Best regards.

Comment: Here is a similar question about using puppeteer for this: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3816

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt: Thanks but I am looking for a Matlab solution.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've missed the tag.

Comment: `webread('http://tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/clienttype.aspx?i=778253364357513')` should pull the data you are looking for.

Comment: @Ash: It gives me a `  0×24001 empty table`

Comment: @user145959 sure, you need to figure out what the right `i` is for your request. The point of the comment is that the website uses requests, and you could make the same to get your data instead of trying to parse the webpage.

Comment: @Ash: How can I send a request in Matlab? Where should I find about the format of request that I should send?